# Visual studio 2015: How to have by default the XAML code, not the split view?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I don't use MUCH the XAML designer, but I appreciate at some time to have the possibility to use, and more, to have the "Properties" windows present to set some properties.

But I would like that when I click on a XAML file, I get the XAML code, without the GUI part. Basically, the Xaml Designer, but not in "split" view.

Is this possible?

I found that it is possible to totally disable the XAML designer, but then:

- I don't get the possibility to just switch to this view(well with Open Width, yes)
- More important, I don't have the "Properties" windows populated with the properties of the currently selected XAML

I also found that there is a setting with a default view(Tools, Options, XAML Designer, Default Document view: SourceView), but this doesn't work(or I didn't understood), I still get the default split view, even after a VS2015 restart.

So is it possible to keep the XAML designer, but have by default only the XAML displayed?

Comment: The **XAML Designer** option you mentioned works as expected for me.

Comment: @jstreet I don't know what I could have done wrong then, because I really set this option, closed all the document, closed Visual studio, reopen, and on double clic, I still have the splited view. What version of VS2015 do you have?

Comment: I have VS Community 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Version 14.0.25424.00

Comment: Option works but you need to delete .vs cache folder in you solution folder otherwise Visual Studio will open xaml designer with the layout you used previously for that xaml file.

Answer (score 29):

Easy Way.

Go to Tools -> Options.

and follow the screen shot.
[image]

Comment: This worked except for the XAML file I had opened in split view (Visual Studio seems to remember the way it ways opened before). So I manually changed it to XAML view, and now it works. Other XAML files open in XAML view.

Comment: Funny thing I've noticed is that at the top it says: "requires restart of Visual Studio".
Seriously?) And the same is still persistent on VS 2019. This is something I couldn't expect to be true, but it is.

Comment: Even 6 years later, they still don't have an option to specify which side of the split the code is on (I want it on the left)

Answer (score 12):

To open `.xaml` files in XAML-only mode, you need to change the **default editor** that `.xaml` files open with. Here's how:

1. Right click on any `.xaml` file.
2. Click on **Open with...**
3. Select **Source Code (Text) Editor**.
4. Click **Set as Default**.
5. Click **OK**.

That's it. Opening any `.xaml` file should now open in full XAML view. To get back to the designer, simply press **Shift** + **F7**, or **Right Click** -> **View Designer**.

The only drawback that I have experienced is that Intellisense doesn't seem to pick up any **resources** (i.e `DynamicResource` and `StaticResource` references) that you may have.

---

If you still want the **Designer** running in the background, use the following instructions:

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Options**.
2. Expand **Text Editor** -> **XAML** -> **Miscellaneous**.
3. Check the **Always open documents in full XAML view** checkbox.

This will open all `.xaml` documents in full XAML view, to switch back to the designer, simply click on the `Design` tab.

Comment: I've already tried that. But my major concern(having the Properties toolbox correctly populated with the current XAML element) is present with this issue

Comment: Could you try option 2? I believe that should show the properties window but I can't verify. The properties window has never worked on the designer for my copy of visual studio.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't exist since VS2015, now it's on XAML Designer, but it's the option that I indicated previously

Comment: Option 2 works perfectly for me with VS2015, only the option is not under Text Editor, but XAML Designer -> Default Document View. Only the source is expanded, and the properties window works if there are no errors on the xaml page.

Answer (score 2):

New place XAML Designer options.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFEJ3.png)